# ReadTimeout for NetworkStream.ReadAsync

Tags: c#, sockets, async-await, timeout, networkstream

When does the [NetworkStream.ReadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync?view=netcore-3.1) task complete? As soon as it receives data for the specified length?

If yes, does it ever return 0? Then the [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netcore-3.1) could be used as the [ReadTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readtimeout?view=netcore-3.1), which is as property only available for synchronous operations, right?

Comment: I would assume that `ReadAsync` fails like `Read` with an `IOException` when the time limit is reached. I think the documentation for `ReadTimeout` is simply incomplete. But I might be wrong and can sadly not verify my claims at the moment

Comment: You can make a research on [sources](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Sockets/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs,c6c772e98dc6926e)

Comment: Neither Read() or ReadAsync() will ever time out on their own.  You'll get an IOException if the underlying Socket is torn down, reset by the peer or some other intermediate device (eg a stateful firewall).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadAsync() will ever "time out" on its own.  Use a CancellationToken if you want to cancel it.  ReadAsync() will return 0 immediately if the underlying socket is closed.

ReadAsync will return as soon as it has data, this could be 1 byte.  It will not wait till the buffer is full.

```
    static async Task StartTcpClientAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Connection from: [{tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}]");

        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        var buffer = new byte[1024];

        while (true)
        {
            int x = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);
            Console.WriteLine($"[{tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}] _ " +
                $"read {x} bytes {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)}");
        }
    }
    static async Task StartTcpServerAsync()
    {
        var tcpListener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999));
        tcpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            _ = StartTcpClientAsync(tcpClient);
        }
    }
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _ = StartTcpServerAsync();
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        await RunSenderAsync();
    }
    static async Task RunSenderAsync()
    {
        var tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 9999);
        var s = tcpClient.GetStream();
        tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
        for (var i = 65; i < 91; i++)
        {
            s.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(i), 0, 1);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

Produces:

```
[127.0.0.1:65201] read 1 bytes A
[127.0.0.1:65201] read 1 bytes B
[127.0.0.1:65201] read 1 bytes C 
[127.0.0.1:65201] read 1 bytes D
[127.0.0.1:65201] read 1 bytes E
[127.0.0.1:65201] read 1 bytes F
...
```